# Declaring a nullable variable in a razor page produces error

Tags: c#, razor

I am getting the following error:

> CS1061  'Task' does not contain a definition for 'data' and no accessible extension method 'data' accepting a first argument of type 'Task' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

This is the line that errors out

```
  _OldRecord = await GetPossibleDuplicateRecord(Convert.ToInt64(OldId)).data;
```

I believe I am getting this error because _OldRecord is null at this time.  I tried to add the ? when I am declaring the variable like this:

```
private PossibleDuplicateRecord? _OldRecord = new PossibleDuplicateRecord();
```

and I still get the error.  A co-worker told me to put the .data at the end of the await and both of these threw the same error.  This is in the code-behind of a razor page if that is any help.  I am out of ideas

Also, I have the proper using reference "using System.Threading.Tasks" so I know that the using directive is there

Comment: You need to parenthesise your awaitable expression i.e. `(await GetPossibleDuplicateRecord(Convert.ToInt64(OldId))).data`.

Answer (score 0):

Priority problem?

```
await GetPossibleDuplicateRecord(Convert.ToInt64(OldId)).data;
```

The way i read it, you await the .data, not the task.

```
(await GetPossibleDuplicateRecord(Convert.ToInt64(OldId))).data
```

would be the data.